# Magento2 print quote data

Tags: magento2

Magento2 How can I print quote data?

```
$quote = $this->quoteRepository->get($order->getQuoteId());
                $quote->setIsActive(1)->setReservedOrderId(null);
                $this->quoteRepository->save($quote);
```

I need to check(print) the quote data, that is being saved. How can I achieve that?

I tried print_r($quote->getData()); but it is throwing error of memory exhausted.

Comment: Did you resolve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because quote has very large amount of data and system memory would be unable to handle it.

You can try printing `array_keys` first like this:

```
print_r(array_keys($quote->getData()));
```

After this you will get all the available keys on quote object, you can then use your required key on `getData` like this:

```
print_r($quote->getData("items"));
```

Hope this will help you